# Router won't connect to computer over cable

Tags: networking, router

I have a Thompson 784 router that connects to the Internet. It works nicely enough.
What is wrong is that I have a shielded Cat 5e cable that goes from my room to the router that's in a another room (~30 metres). Both ends are the same; both ends are done nicely; I've tested it with a cable tester and every wire connects. However, when i connect my computer to my router neither one will find the other.

So would anyone be nice and please explain what is wrong.

p.s.: I have tried many different cable ends (currently it on standard/A), the cable is tested both ways (as it should be) and yes I'm at my wit's end =(

Comment: It is a normal cable or a cross cable? Does your router or computer support DMX (if one or both do then do not bother checking if the cable is cross).

Comment: as i said its normal (same at both ends) and il check dmx and writeback

Comment: well then i got it working (on my 7th cable ending) now im completely dumb folded as to why the heck didn't it work on the first or third or the sixth time. @Hennes i thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I would try moving them next to each other and testing them with a cable you **know** works.

Comment: @trideceth12 i thank you for correcting my post but i got it working. I tested the cable and the router and the computer as well. everything worked just not together.                             until now =)

Comment: post that as an answer, and self select it when you can, please!

Comment: @yyy and please include the solution in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution:
Was doing the cable endings again and it started to work.